# Как добиться необходимого фона, путем накладывания фона с прозрачностью в сетке бутстрап?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, bootstrap

Мне необходимо добиться такого цвета как на макете путем накладывания одного фона поверх другого, и так чтобы он размещался только в по сетке бутстрап. Я попытался решить это так:
Взял цвет пипеткой в фотошопе и перевел его в `rgba` и с `before` задал:

```
.background-pink::before
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    background-color: rgba(251, 239, 238, .1)
    z-index: 2
```

Но получил какой-то мутный фон, а не третий цвет, так же не понял как это уместить в сетку бутстрап.

Второй способ:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="header-menu background-pink">
        <div class="row">`
```

создавая див между контейнером и ров и так в каждой секции, но может быть это можно было решить поизящнее не нагромождая код. И в секции меняется только блок с  "play now", а видео(на скрине), вообще не меняет цвет poster, наложенный на видео. 
В общем, пожалуйста, помогите "сдвинутся с мертвой точки".

[image]

Вот весь код секции:

html

```
<section class="video-container">
    <div class="video">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="background-pink">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="video-text" style="width:500px; height:300px;">
                            <h3>WATCH BEHIND THE SCENE</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A alias commodi eos debitis numquam quasi, minima odit atque accusamus, enim dolore dolorem sit iste ipsum quidem vitae esse aliquid voluptas!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="video-play background-pink">
                            <div class="youtube" id="MIwp8pmwl-Y" style="width:670px; height:420px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

sass-код

```
.video-container
    .video
        background-color: #171f23
        .video-text
            position: relative
            left: -65px
            text-align: center
            h3
                font-family: "RobotoBold", sans-serif
                font-size: 30px
                letter-spacing: 2px
                color: #e7e7e7
            p
                font-family: "RobotoThin", sans-serif
                font-size: em(14px)
                color: #919191
```

Comment: можна больше кода ?

Comment: Да, конечно. Уже отредактировал.

Comment: @DavidKern, задеклайнить твою правку надо было...

Comment: А что это значит?)

Comment: как я понял вам надо 2 диба на том же самом уровне толка один будет  с фонам темнее ?